# MVC3: NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, jqgrid

I'm getting NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code exception when I'm trying to sort JQGrid value.

```
     public ActionResult GetSearch(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
            {
                if (sidx != "")
                {
//In the Session["ResourceSearch"] I have loaded the values
    DataContractClass[] SortResult = Session["ResourceSearch"] as DataContractClass[];
    //Sort the JQGrid value from input 'sidx'                
        SortResult = SortResult.OrderBy(p => p.GetType().GetProperty(sidx).GetValue(p, null)).ToArray() as DataContractClass[];
    //Load data here
                }
            }
```

[image]

I'm facing problem only if the int property as the input to `sidx`.But If any string property to `sidx` no issues.I'm able to sort the data.

Answer (score 2):

Either:

- `p` is null in the lambda
- there is no public instance property with the name *exactly* (i.e. case matches as well) equal to `sidx` on the type represented by `p`

My guess is the second.

Check that there is actually a public property with the name equal to whatever value `sidx` is when this exception is thrown.  By the way - that's basically what the second help string in the message box is telling you to do.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply! I'm not clear still.. During the exception 'sidx' contains int variable & this variable declared as public in the property and its not null I can checked in the immediate window. any solution?